# Asp.NET MVC and Azure storage

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

We are currently working on moving our Asp.NET MVC app from a shared hosting provider to Azure. Our users can upload files such as images and documents to our server and we store these files under `app-url/content/data` which works pretty well.

**Question:**

Is it safe to keep doing the same thing and uploading files under `app-url/content/data` ? I've read about the Azure blob storage but we would like minimize the amount of work required to move to Azure (this is definitely something we could do in the coming months)

Comment: Yes it is safe. We have a similar situation and the user uploaded files stay intact after our VSTS continuous integration deployments.

Comment: Thanks! Awesome. Will go with this then :)

Answer (score 2):

Azure provides a number of storage options such as Azure SQL, DocumentDB, Azure Blob storage and more, you can use anyone. If your application is just storing the images, Azure Blob storage is the best option.

> Is it safe to keep doing the same thing and uploading files under app-url/content/data ?

Definitely, the security is not concerns to Azure Customers. It is Microsoft's concern you can learn about Azure security from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/TrustCenter/Security/default.aspx).

> we would like minimize the amount of work required to move to Azure.

This depends upon your application's back-end storage and resource management. If you are setting a new Azure VM for running your application, it might take long. If you are about to use Azure Web Apps (Recommended), it will minimize your migration workload as you may be already familiar with.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. My concern is that if we put the images under `app-url/content/data` a developer can erase the data by mistake when running a deploy.

Comment: It depends upon how your application is structured! If your application is like `app-url/content[controller]/data[action]` and where your action is storing that received files, replace them with an Azure blob API to store them.

Comment: If you want to move your images from your current infrastructure to Azure blob, you can try Azure blob Import\Export service. You can learn about it from [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-import-export-service/).

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned in the question above, I am well aware of the Azure blob infrastructure but I want to attack the problem in steps. First step is to move everything 'as-is' to Azure, the second step would be to make good use of the Azure offerings

Comment: For first step, try (as said) Azure Blob Import\Export service. For second step, it depends upon you that how you better built your application which consumes computing resources (RAM and Processes) as low as possible to reduce the cost that your get.